# How do I compile and run Java Classes for Apache Storm program?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have been learning Apache Storm for Big Data Analysis from [Tutorials Point.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/index.htm)

I installed all files and configured them as mentioned [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_installation.htm)
 Now when I try to follow instructions and run a Simple Mobile Call Log Analyzer program with 4 java files as mentioned [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_storm/apache_storm_working_example.htm) , I encounter an error

```
javac: invalid flag:
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using to compile your program?

Comment: I navigated to the directory holding my java classes and I also replaced the path to Apache-storm lib where my apache storm lib is located and I run following command



`javac -cp “/path/to/storm/apache-storm-0.9.5/lib/*” *.java`

Comment: Have you double-checked that the path is correct? Keep in mind you have to use backslashes instead of forward slashes if you're running Windows.

Comment: Yes I checked the path 7-8 times. It is correct.

Comment: So these files are saved in `lib`? Have you tried navigating to its parent directory and then entering `javac lib/*.java` instead?

Comment: Notice the command is in following format

javac -cp <path to jar libraries> <sourcefiles>

where <path to jar libraries> :- `/home/milinjoshi/Twitter_Analysis/storm/apache-storm/lib/*`

<sourcefiles> :- *.java

pathtolibaries :- path where all the jar files for Apache Storm are stored.
sourcefiles :- `*.java` as I am executing the command from the directory where all the Java classes are stored

Comment: Have you tried to remove hte `"` from you classpath? Btw: if you use a package structure in you java code (ie, not using default package) you need to execute javac from top level folder and specify path to java files.

Comment: Not working even after removing `"`. Can you elaborate on package structure?